# Import image to folder, image path to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to import image into folder and its path into database. However the path is going in database but the image is not importing in folder. Any help will be highly appreciable. Below is my code so far which I tried. Thanks in advance

```
<?php
$page = "newProduct";

include('header.php') ?>

<?php


if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $fileName=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
    $fileSize=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"]/1024;
    $fileType=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"];
    $fileTmpName=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];

    //if($fileType=="application/msword"){
        if($fileSize<=200000){

            //New file name
            $random=rand(1111,9999);
            $newFileName=$random.$fileName;

            //File upload path
            $uploadPath="upload/".$newFileName;

            //function for upload file
            if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$uploadPath)){
                echo "Successful<BR>";
                echo "File Name :".$newFileName."<BR>";
                echo "File Size :".$fileSize." kb"."<BR>";
                echo "File Type :".$fileType."<BR>";
            }
            if(!empty($_POST['product_name'])){
                $insert_query = "insert into product (product_name,active_status,product_price, product_cate_id,in_stock,product_url,
                            front_product_image,main_product_image, product_desc,product_short_desc)
        values('".$_POST['product_name']."','".$_POST['isActive']."','".$_POST['product_price']."',
        '".$_POST['product_category']."','".$_POST['in_stock']."','".$uploadPath."','".$_POST['fileToUpload']."','".$_POST['fileToUpload']."',
        '".$_POST['long_desc']."','".$_POST['short_desc']."')";
                mysqlInsert($insert_query);
                echo "data inserted";
            }else{
                echo "please add title";

            }
        }
        else{
            echo "Maximum upload file size limit is 200 kb";
        }
}

    ?>

    <div class="row report-dashboard-dropdown-row col-lg-11 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-item col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <label>Product Name</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="product name" name="product_name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-item col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <label>Product Price</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="product price" name="product_price">
            </div>
            <div class="form-item col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <label>Product Image</label>
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" class="btn btn-default">
            </div>
            <div class="form-item col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <label>Product category</label>
                 <?php
    $sql = "select * from categories";
    $rows = mysqlFetchRows($sql);
?>
                <select name="product_category">
                <?php foreach($rows as $catogaries){ ?>
                    <option><?php echo $catogaries['category_name'];  ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="text-muted bootstrap-admin-box-title">Product Short Description</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bootstrap-admin-panel-content">
                        <textarea id="ckeditor_standard" name="short_desc"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="text-muted bootstrap-admin-box-title">Product Long Description</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bootstrap-admin-panel-content">
                        <textarea id="ckeditor_full" name="long_desc"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-item col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <label>Product active Status</label>
                <div class="radios">
                    <div class="radioBtn">
                        <span>Yes</span><input type="radio" value="yes" name="isActive" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="radioBtn">
                        <span>No</span><input type="radio" value="no" name="isActive" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row btn_submit">
                <input class="sub_btn" type="reset" value="Clear" name="clear">
                <input class="sub_btn" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: What are the permissions on the `upload/` folder? You might want to make sure the user apache is running under has permission to write to that directory

Comment: @vandsh is along the lines I am. Also do you get any error?

Comment: no m not getting error

Answer (score 0):

You are missing form attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Your form tag should be following:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your form by below script:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-item col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <label>Product Name</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="product name" name="product_name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-item col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <label>Product Price</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="product price" name="product_price">
            </div>
            <div class="form-item col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <label>Product Image</label>
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" class="btn btn-default">
            </div>
            <div class="form-item col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <label>Product category</label>
                 <?php
    $sql = "select * from categories";
    $rows = mysqlFetchRows($sql);
?>
                <select name="product_category">
                <?php foreach($rows as $catogaries){ ?>
                    <option><?php echo $catogaries['category_name'];  ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="text-muted bootstrap-admin-box-title">Product Short Description</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bootstrap-admin-panel-content">
                        <textarea id="ckeditor_standard" name="short_desc"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="text-muted bootstrap-admin-box-title">Product Long Description</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bootstrap-admin-panel-content">
                        <textarea id="ckeditor_full" name="long_desc"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-item col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <label>Product active Status</label>
                <div class="radios">
                    <div class="radioBtn">
                        <span>Yes</span><input type="radio" value="yes" name="isActive" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="radioBtn">
                        <span>No</span><input type="radio" value="no" name="isActive" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row btn_submit">
                <input class="sub_btn" type="reset" value="Clear" name="clear">
                <input class="sub_btn" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply :) but no change came after replacing the script.

Comment: where is your upload folder and what error you got.

Comment: my upload folder is on same directory where i am having this page newproduct.php

Answer (score 0):

[Through Upload Image by PHP in W3School.com](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Your form should add:

> `<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Declare in header upload:

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Should Check if image file is a actual image or fake image:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
```

Should Check if file already exists:

```
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

Should Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error:

```
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
//Add your insert statement
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this but I applied this. I am getting this error. " Sorry, file already exists.Sorry, your file was not uploaded.please add title ",  However there is no file in upload folder.